# Code style: change lots of similar overloads

Tags: java, java-8

For a while I have been writing lots of really similar overloads. Maybe I am doing something wrong or just don't know some language features to make it more compact.

```
public void foo(Object bar){
    try(Transaction tx = persistence.createTransaction()){
         foo(bar,persistence.getEntityManager());
         tx.commit();
    }
}
public void foo(Object bar,EntityManager em)/*...*/
```

It is just seems raw and I believe there must be a way to wrap similar methods I just don't know.

Comment: Having such "refined" methods is fine - the real question is: do you need to make them all public? If the second method would simply be private, that would be fine "clean code" in my eyes.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @GhostCat I *think* he is referring to something like an utility around `Closeables` from guava let's say, but in java-8 I guess

Comment: What you want is an AOP library

Comment: Yes i belive guava's `Closeables` seems close to what i am looking what.
Just get me right: i never had a person to review my code and right now thonn of similar templates with create transaction->overload seems not raw from my perspective. Similar to overloads for @Nullable attributes.

Comment: That really depends on what's in the other `foo` method (ie how similar they are). If it's mostly the same with slight variation, you might be able to create a `Builder` that aggregates arguments to a `Strategy` object.

Comment: And about private and public methods - yes i need it to be public cose first method will be called from user client without opened transaction when second one ether from other methods of class or hooks with opened transactions.
But, to be fair I am not always clearly see the gap between access modifications and when you should use private or public "just in case..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TransactionRunnable {
    void runTransactionCode(EntityManager em);
}

public void runInNewTransaction(TransactionRunnable code) {
    try(Transaction tx = persistence.createTransaction()){
        code.runTransactionCode(persistence.getEntityManager());
        tx.commit();
    }
}

public void foo(Object bar, EntityManager em) { /*...*/ }
public void baz(String str, EntityManager em) { /*...*/ }
```

Foo can then be called inside its own transaction using

```
runInNewTransaction((em) -> foo(myBar, em));
```

... and similarly ...

```
runInNewTransaction((em) -> baz("hello", em));
```

Obviously, the `TransactionRunnable` interface can be changed so its method declares an exception, if needed.

Comment: Thanks it is exactly what i needed. At the back of my head i think that there is should be lambda-solution but couldn't exactly find how to do it.
Now code (In my opinion) looks a lot more readable.